# Can I use partner account fields in a report?

Tags: reporting, custom-field, account

I am creating an "Opportunities with Products" report.  Is there any way I can use more partner fields than what are exposed by default?  I presume the answer is no, but, I wanted to ask just to be safe.

Below is a picture of what I am able to use.  Since the partner is really just another account, I was hoping to have access to the other fields available on the account object.

[image: partner fields]

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of reports that can suit your needs:

1. Custom Report Types (Setup > Create > Report Types). You can use the custom report type builder to build an "Opportunity with Partners" report; the primary object will be Opportunities, and the first child will be Partners. From there, you can add all of the account fields you desire.
2. Use the Joined Report type. On the Reports tab, choose New Report..., then use the Opportunities with Partners built-in report type, then choose "Joined Report" under the report type dropdown (the default is Tabular), then click "Add Report Type", and finally choose Accounts. This configuration will let you link opportunity partners to additional account data.

Comment: I misspoke in my question; I was actually trying to do an opportunity with products report.  I presume it's not possible to pull in all the related partner fields into that report?  I still gave you +1 as this answer is helpful.

Comment: @Ek0nomik In that case, use Opportunities with Products for the first report, and join Opportunities with Partners for the second. You'll get all information you could want, although it appears that Joined Reports cannot be exported.